# Cmake - Find_package NO_DEFAULT_PATH not working properly?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to include OpenCv in a project, I actually have 2 times the same version of this lib on my computer. One compiled with additionnal needed functions ( Cuda&OpenGl support) at /good/path and one compiled without thoses needed function at /old/non/suitable/path.

I'm curently doing this in my cmake :

```
message(${OpenCV_LIBS})
message(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(${HINTS})
find_package( OpenCV 3.2.0 REQUIRED CONFIG PATHS "/good/path" NO_DEFAULT_PATH )
message(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

The first 3 messages reports errors, in other words the variable are empty.
And the last message writes "/old/non/suitable/path/include"

According to the [find package documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html), with adding the NO_DEFAULT_PATH option I should check only the explicit PATHS and HINTS but HINTS is empty as I checked it.

Does anyone have any idee on why I find the other old library instead of the one in the /good/path which once more should be the only path checked ?

Edit : For anyone having the same issue of not successfully selecting the wanted library, one solution is to rename the LibConfig.cmake of the old library to anything else. That will force cmake to find the last library. 
Still, that's pretty awful and I have no idee why NO_DEAULF_PATH ins't working as it should be. 
I'm waiting here a few days in case somebody sees an answer and if there isn't any response, I will open an issue directly on the cmake website.

Comment: Next thing to check is `OpenCV_DIR` variable - it contains *cached* location of `*Config.cmake` script. But it is better simply remove build directory and try again.

Comment: Delete OpenCV cache variables (remove entries in GUI) then reconfigure. The find_package command will not execute as intended if it finds out that expected output variables already exist including OpenCV_DIR as @Tsyvarev commented.

Comment: thanks for you answers. At the moment, on OpenCV_DIR, I have the good path, not sure it was the case yesterday buring my tests. If I understand correctly your words, this cached location is in the build directory. I cannot be sure that this is the reason it didn't work but it can be. I believe that it should be mentionned in the function documentation, should I ask for an add in your opinions ? Btw, what do you want to say by "remove entries in GUI", remove the build directory ?

Comment: Well i cannot edit anymore, did not know this rule, I just wanted to say that I'm pretty sure that "remove entry in GUI" is pertty different than remove the build directory =P,  but still no clue about what you meant. thanks again for your comments ;)

Comment: I was using CLion for this and had a hell of a time until I did "Rebuild" instead of just "Build." Took me too long to guess that some stuff was being cached somewhere somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the build directory is the way to go.

Otherwise a cached path in the build directory overwrite the path modification in the cmake.

Ps : The answer is in Tsyvarev comment, I'm answering myself to close the question.